# Excel VBA changing color on cell at the time

Tags: vba, excel

Maybe due to my poor English some of you may misunderstood what I wanted to do. Anyways, here is the code that I wanted. After many trial and errors I made it but I doubt its the best way but it works =). If anyone know how to make the code better please tell me =).
I previous post is also below this new code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim row As Integer

For row = 1 To 1000
If Cells(row, "A").Value = "Yes" Then
    Range("B" & row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4


    End If

    If Cells(row, "A").Value = "yes" Then
    Range("B" & row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4


    End If


Next row

End Sub
```

**Previous post**

I have written a VBA code in excel where I want to change a cell color everytime I write  "yes". In this case I write "yes" in column E and column A should change color. I have used a for loop but it does not run as I want. I have a feeling I am thinking a bit wrong...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cellNr As Long

For cellNr = 1 To 5

    If Range("E" & cellNr).Value = "yes" Then

       Range("A" & cellNr).Interior.ColorIndex = 5   

       Else
          ActiveCell(0, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
       End If

Next cellNr

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you write VBA for something Excel can do natively?

Comment: @teylyn is referring to conditional formatting. no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional formatting with a formula. Starting in row 1 the formula required is

```
=$E1="yes"
```

[image]

Comment: I am aware of this feature but what if you have 100 yes that is alternating in row E, that is yes,yes no,yes,no for example. I are you able to color then with this feature?

Comment: @user3776800 Yes. You can apply Teylyn's conditional format to range A1:A100 and $E1 will be the cell checked for formatting A1. E2 will be checked for formatting A2 and so on.

Comment: Just set up a conditional format for `=$E1="yes"` and again for `=$E1="no"`.  Just make sure to only use the `$` to the column (`E`) and not the row (`1`).  Then just drag the cell down and choose `Fill formatting only`.

Comment: This feature seems not so convenient if I add a new row and type yes everytime, thats why using VBA is more better once you have figured out how to code it...I have seen such macro before but it was long time ago and now I want to do it.

Comment: @pnuts The OP's code shows one color being used for true and another for false.  I suppose `$E1<>"yes"` could be used as well, but the OP mentioned `yes` and `no` combinations in his comment above.

Comment: @user3776800 If you create an Excel Table (Insert > Table), stuff like conditional formatting (and formulas and data validation) will carry over into new rows. Why don't you try to understand what Excel can do out of the box before you use VBA to re-create functionality that already exists?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do with the following line:

```
ActiveCell(0, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
```

Replace it with:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
```

As far as I know, the line I told you to remove will always throw an error. It doesn't make any sense syntactically. You should use the Offset function to get positions relative to the Active Cell. But also, this offset function will throw an error if your active cell is in column A or B because there are less than 2 columns to the left of the active cell.

Comment: @pnuts True that.  I only made the edit to remove the 2nd `there` from your edit.  I guess I oops'd also.  I sent a fix.

Comment: @pnuts Oh whoops! Must have gotten distracted while proofreading. Thanks for completing my sentence. That is what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rOfInterest As Range
    Set rOfInterest = Range("E1:E5")
    If Intersect(Target, rOfInterest) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = Target.Value
    If v = "yes" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -4).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, -4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
End Sub
```

**and make sure the macro is in the worksheet code area.**